# How to get telnet execution result code from shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, telnet

Using the following shell code for remote telnet request:

```
{
sleep 5
echo admin
sleep 3
echo pass
sleep 3
echo ls
sleep 5
echo exit
} | telnet 172.16.1.1
```

I want to check if telnet connection was successful or not. Trying to use $?:

```
echo $?
```

But it always returns "1", even if telnet connection was OK.

Comment: Use `expect(1)` to script interactive programs.

Comment: I second this. Expect is extremely useful for automating interactive tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telnet is exceptionally difficult to script in this way, there is a high degree of asynchronicity with the time it takes to establish a connection and for your intended actions to complete.  [expect](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/The-Linux-Unix-Command-Expect.htm) was created for exactly this kind of purpose.  You launch a program, like telnet, then declare a series of expectations - eg, when 'username: ' is emitted from the program, and an action to trigger (eg: typing in the username).

There are also libraries or wrappers for expect in many languages:

- [python expect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html)
- [ruby expect](http://www.42klines.com/2010/08/14/what-to-expect-from-the-ruby-expect-library.html)
- [perl expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod)

Here is an example that drives telnet to make an HTTP HEAD request:

```
set timeout 20

spawn telnet localhost 80

expect "Connected to "
send "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

expect "HTTP 200 OK"
```

Given all of this, I feel I must point out that telnet is considered insecure.  [Ssh](http://www.openssh.com/) is a much better choice and supports better choices for authentication (eg: [public/private key auth](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/)), [restrictions for commands](http://www.wallix.org/2011/10/18/restricting-remote-commands-over-ssh/) that can be run (via .ssh/authorized_keys).  With ssh, and ssh-keys set up, your script reduces to a single shell command:

```
ssh user@hostname ls
```

ssh has great support for safe, secure remote command execution.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm remembering correctly, this expect script does what you're doing above.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet 172.16.1.1

expect username:
send admin
expect password:
send pass
expect "\$ "
send ls
expect "\$ "
send exit
```

Here's a useful link for getting started: http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html